# Permissions required to install License?

Tags: permissions, csom, license

I try to install a license using CSOM using the following method:

```
SharePoint.Client.Utilities.Utility.ImportAppLicense
```

When I do this I receive an "access Denied" error. What kind of permission is required to allow this? I currently have write Permission on Web, Taxonomy and Site Collection (Entered through AppManifest.xml)

Comment: I think you need Full Control.

Comment: My error. I actually had Read-Permissions on SiteCollection instead of Write.Permissions. After I corrected that, everything worked fine